# Style.Visibility doesnt let element do animation?

Tags: css, angular

I have two functions which should hide and make my element (Image), whose `id` is "Brandish":

```
hideBrandish(): void {
    document.getElementById('Brandish').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
showBrandish(): void {
    document.getElementById('Brandish').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Now I have a function, that calls first `this.showBrandish()`.

Then I have a function, that calls the `.className = 'skillimage'`, which moves the image per `@keyframes`:

```
this.moveSkillImage(); {
    if (this.chosenHero.skill.name === 'Brandish') {
        document.getElementById('Brandish').className = 'skillImage';
    }
}
```

Finally I call `hideBrandish()`.

The problem is that my animation isn't processing, instead my image just gets hidden. Why is that?

Comment: I think you are looking for `opacity` rather than `visibility`. For `visibility`, there are no defined interpolated values between `hidden` and `visible`.

Comment: I already tried the same with opacity. Still the same result

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?